Random replacement in array
In the spirit of this interesting article of Stephen Wolfram I also decided to study some issues related to mutations.
I’m working with simple {0,1} arrays and I’ve chosen this definition of mutation:

Do nothing
Delete random element of array
Insert RandomInteger[] at random position
Inverse random element

This code works well:
someMutation[arr_] := With[{pos = RandomInteger[{1, Length@arr}]},
   RandomChoice[{
     arr,
     Insert[arr, RandomInteger[], pos],
     Delete[arr, pos],
     ReplaceAt[arr, x_ :> If[x == 0, 1, 0], pos]
     }]];

but I very like Mathematica patterns conception, so looks like code can be written much better in terms of patterns and replacements.
Is it possible?

I can't see any patterns. I only see a random position.

maybe aMutation[arr_] :=  ReplaceAt[arr,   x_ :> Splice@RandomChoice[{{x}, {1 - x}, {}, {x, RandomInteger[]}}],   RandomInteger[{1, Length@arr}]]?

also aMutation2[arr_] :=  MapAt[Splice @ RandomChoice[{{#}, {1 - #}, {}, {#, RandomInteger[]}}] &, arr,   RandomInteger[{1, Length@arr}]]
